# How do JS modules prevent custom elements defined inside from exposing their APIs?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, es6-modules, custom-element

This does not work:

```html
<!-- wtf.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <script type="module" src="./wtf.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  const myElement = document.createElement('my-element')
  document.body.appendChild(myElement)
  myElement.callMe()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// wtf.js
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  callMe() {
    window.alert('I am called!')
  }
})
```

Firefox throws me a nasty exception on line `myElement.callMe()`. Apparently, *"`myElement.callMe is not a function`"*.

I am confused why is that so? To my understanding, as soon as I type `const myElement = document.createElement('my-element')`, I am receiving an object whose type is not a generic `HTMLElement` but an object of my class I wrote that extends `HTMLElement`! And this class exposes `callMe`.

I have confirmed that my use of modules seems to be the culprit here. This code works as expected:

```html
<!-- wtf.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super()
    }

    callMe() {
        window.alert('I am called!')
    }
  })

  const myElement = document.createElement('my-element')
  document.body.appendChild(myElement)
  myElement.callMe()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes I know that things defined in a module are scoped to this module. But here it does not even seem (to me) to be a scoping issue. For example, if I do **inside a module** something like that:

```js
function callMe() {/*blah blah */}

window.callMe = callMe
```

then I will be able to use `callMe` **outside of the module** anyway, because the module exposed this function through other means than `export` (this time through assigning it to the global `window` object).

The same, to my understanding, should be happening in my use case. Even though I define `callMe` in a class scoped to the module, this class method should be accessible outside of the module by the virtue of it being a property of an object of this class that is exposed by calling `document.createElement('my-element')`. Yet manifestly, this does not happen.

This is really weird to me. It almost seems as if the module was enforcing its scoping by ***tangling with types unrelated functions return***(!!) - so in this case, it is just as if the module magically forces `document.createElement` to cast the object it returns up in the inheritance hierarchy (to `HTMLElement`)?!?! This is mind-blowing to me.

Could someone please clear my confusion?

(And if I define a custom element inside a module, how may I expose its API outside of this module?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a `<script type="module">` [implicitly has a `defer` attribute](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/#defer-by-default), so it doesn't run immediately.

> Even though I define callMe in a class scoped to the module, this class method should be accessible outside of the module

Yes, it is. The problem is just that it is defined asynchronously :-) To use stuff from a module, you should explicitly `import` that module to declare the dependency, which makes sure it is evaluated in the right order. It would also work if your global script was `defer`red somehow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title></title>
  <script type="module" src="./wtf.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module">
    import './wtf.js';
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const myElement = document.createElement('my-element')
    document.body.appendChild(myElement)
    myElement.callMe()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am confused still. From MDN documentation of the `script` tag's `defer` attribute: "*This attribute must not be used if the `src` attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.*" Is MDN wrong here?

Comment: Sadly, MDN seems to be correct. From the [WHATWG standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) : "*The async and defer attributes are boolean attributes that indicate how the script should be evaluated. Classic scripts may specify defer or async, but must not specify either unless the src attribute is present. Module scripts may specify the async attribute, but must not specify the defer attribute.*" So I'm not sure how may I mark my global script with `defer`?

Comment: On the other hand, marking my global script with `type="module"` seems to solve the problem

Comment: ... or use ˋwhenDefined"

Comment: Oh wait, `type="module"` doesn't really work dunno why. Perhaps I need to explicitely mark a dependence

Comment: Not even explicitely `import`ing helps. I give up, I have to use `whenDefined` I guess

Comment: @gaazkam Are you sure? That should definitely work. What did you try?

Comment: Wait no, importing works (I hope). Didnt work because of a typo on my side (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You could also wait for the window.onload event to execute your inline script:

```
document.onload = () => {
  const myElement = document.createElement('my-element')
  document.body.appendChild(myElement)
  myElement.callMe()
}
```

Alternately, you could use *classic* `<script>` loading to be sure your custom element is loaded synchronously:

```
<script src="./wtf.js"></script>
```